# how to write v4L capturing program for usb web cam (640x480)

Tags: v4l

i installed the usb webcam driver in linux 2.6 version
then i want to capture using V4L please any one reply me how can i write the program to capture using webcam

Answer (score 0):

I work with V4l using the reference of the linuxTV (http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/). They have the documentation about V4l and some examples. Take a look at the following example (i got from the linuxTV):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include "../libv4l/include/libv4l2.h"

#define CLEAR(x) memset(&(x), 0, sizeof(x))

struct buffer {
        void   *start;
        size_t length;
};

static void xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
{
        int r;

        do {
                r = v4l2_ioctl(fh, request, arg);
        } while (r == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));

        if (r == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct v4l2_format              fmt;
        struct v4l2_buffer              buf;
        struct v4l2_requestbuffers      req;
        enum v4l2_buf_type              type;
        fd_set                          fds;
        struct timeval                  tv;
        int                             r, fd = -1;
        unsigned int                    i, n_buffers;
        char                            *dev_name = "/dev/video0";
        char                            out_name[256];
        FILE                            *fout;
        struct buffer                   *buffers;

        fd = v4l2_open(dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
        if (fd < 0) {
                perror("Cannot open device");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        CLEAR(fmt);
        fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        fmt.fmt.pix.width       = 640;
        fmt.fmt.pix.height      = 480;
        fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_INTERLACED;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt);
        if (fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat != V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24) {
                printf("Libv4l didn't accept RGB24 format. Can't proceed.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((fmt.fmt.pix.width != 640) || (fmt.fmt.pix.height != 480))
                printf("Warning: driver is sending image at %dx%d\n",
                        fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);

        CLEAR(req);
        req.count = 2;
        req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req);

        buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));
        for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < req.count; ++n_buffers) {
                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index       = n_buffers;

                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf);

                buffers[n_buffers].length = buf.length;
                buffers[n_buffers].start = v4l2_mmap(NULL, buf.length,
                              PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                              fd, buf.m.offset);

                if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[n_buffers].start) {
                        perror("mmap");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i) {
                CLEAR(buf);
                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index = i;
                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
        }
        type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;

        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type);
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                do {
                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(fd, &fds);

                        /* Timeout. */
                        tv.tv_sec = 2;
                        tv.tv_usec = 0;

                        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                } while ((r == -1 && (errno = EINTR)));
                if (r == -1) {
                        perror("select");
                        return errno;
                }

                CLEAR(buf);
                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf);

                sprintf(out_name, "out%03d.ppm", i);
                fout = fopen(out_name, "w");
                if (!fout) {
                        perror("Cannot open image");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fprintf(fout, "P6\n%d %d 255\n",
                        fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);
                fwrite(buffers[buf.index].start, buf.bytesused, 1, fout);
                fclose(fout);

                xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
        }

        type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type);
        for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                v4l2_munmap(buffers[i].start, buffers[i].length);
        v4l2_close(fd);

        return 0;
}
```